# Visual Studio 2015 Application overlay windows 10

Tags: windows, visual-studio, software-design

I want to make an application that starts up when windwos is started, after that the application is full screen on top of everything and you can't close it or use anything of windows, only the application I build. I know how to let my application start up and make it full screen etc. but I dont know how to block all the windows 10 functions, like disable ALT-Tab, ALT-f4 and all that things. So the user can only see and use my application. I searched the whole day but couldn't find anything for this.

Example cash registers at the stores, they run on windwos but they got this software overlay only the cash register software is usable.

Please need some help with this.

Comment: This takes configuration, not programming.  Google "windows setup kiosk app" for basic hits.

Comment: Okay thanks, I will check it out !